# Plotting two datasets with incomplete data in same graph

Tags: python, plotly

My dataframe consists of two columns, the shareprice in every workday and the eps. The shareprice is only available on workdays, while the eps is only available quarterly on a saturday. Now I want to plot both graphs in the same visualization, with two y-axes.

```
            close   eps
date
...         
2020-04-01  240.91  NaN
2020-03-31  254.29  NaN
2020-03-30  254.81  NaN
2020-03-28     NaN  2.59
2020-03-27  247.74  NaN
2020-03-26  258.44  NaN
...
2019-12-28     NaN  5.04
2019-12-27  289.80  NaN
...
```

My approach so far is using plotly:

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df.index,
            y=df["close"],
            name = "Price"
        ),
        secondary_y = False,
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df.dropna(subset=["eps"]),
            y=df["eps"],
            name = "EPS",
        ),
        secondary_y = True,
    )

    
    fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="Price",
        secondary_y=False
    )
    fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="EPS",
        secondary_y=True,
    )
    
    fig.show()
```

However, I end up with a graph, but the EPS are not shown. I want `eps`, to be a line of connected dots, for all the missing datapoints in the `eps` column.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what if you want a sort of stepwise plot or just join dots with a line. In the first case I think that you can use `df["eps"].fillna(method="ffill")` while on the second `df["eps"].interpolate()`

## Generate data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2020-12-31')})

df["close"] = np.abs(np.random.randn(len(df))) * 300
df["eps"] = np.abs(np.random.randn(len(df))) * 10

df["close"] = np.where(df["date"].dt.weekday>=5,
                       np.nan,
                       df["close"])

df["eps"] = np.where((df["date"].dt.month%4==0) & 
                     (df["date"].dt.weekday==5),
                     df["eps"],
                     np.nan)

grp = df.set_index("date").groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))["eps"].last().reset_index()

df = df.drop("eps", axis=1)
df = pd.merge(df, grp, how="left", on="date")

df = df.set_index("date")
```

## Using `fillna(method="ffill")`

```py
df["eps_fillna"] = df["eps"].fillna(method="ffill")

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df.index,
            y=df["close"],
            name = "Price"
        ),
        secondary_y = False,
    )
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df.index,
            y=df["eps_fillna"],
            name = "EPS",

        ),
        secondary_y = True,
    )

    
fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="Price",
        secondary_y=False
    )
fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="EPS",
        secondary_y=True,
    )
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

## Using `interpolate()`

```py
df["eps_interpolate"] = df["eps"].interpolate()

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df.index,
            y=df["close"],
            name = "Price"
        ),
        secondary_y = False,
    )
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df.index,
            y=df["eps_interpolate"],
            name = "EPS",

        ),
        secondary_y = True,
    )

    
fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="Price",
        secondary_y=False
    )
fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text="EPS",
        secondary_y=True,
    )
    
fig.show()
```

[image]